# How to place html code in thank you mesage of contact form 7 wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, contact-form-7

Can any one help me to add a button in thankyou message ofcontact form7.

I have added a custom upload button post. I want to show the upload link after user fills up the contact form in post list page.

I have added this code but the download link became static and it redirects to the link

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    //jQuery(document).on('mailsent.wpcf7', function(){
    //document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    //document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    if(jQuery('.wpcf7-mail-sent-ok').length!==0){
    var redirect_to = jQuery('#dynamichidden-attachment').attr("value");
    if( typeof(redirect_to)!=='undefined' && redirect_to!='' ){
        window.location.href= redirect_to;

    }
    }
});
</script>
```

In my contact form I have used dynamic hidden field

```
[dynamichidden dynamichidden-attachment id:dynamichidden-attachment "thepostattachment"]
```

Can any one help me with this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hey, can you show me the screenshot what do you want to try exactly I am little confused?

Comment: ohh Yes, I am trying to put a link in category page under every post , when user click on the link the contact form opens in a popup and asks for name, email,phone number. After user filled up that successfully, I want to show him button with link which is the uploaded file perticullally for that post

Comment: Hello @ R.K.Bhardwaj Do you know any plug in for this?

Comment: if you show me your website and proper guide i can do it for you

Comment: I need to add HTML code in thank you message of Contact form7.. That is the need

Comment: My website is in local machine..I can not share it..Sorry

Comment: add this script to your contact form additional setting on_sent_ok: "location='<---your site page which you redirect ---->?level=1&'+ $('form.wpcf7-form').serialize();"

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit ablour this @Ravi Sukhadia

Comment: maybe it's possible with javascript and append child in DOM ...

Comment: There is a filter `wpcf7_display_message` , callback accepts 2 params - message and status - you can do some replacing in this filter and return altered message :)